# Fourier Transform of conjugate variables

Tags: fourier-transform

If I have a continuous function in one of a pair of conjugate variables and perform a Fourier Transform with respect to the other conjugate variable will I always get discrete values like happens going from time to a set of frequency.

Comment: What are conjugate variables?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables

Comment: I don't understand, the Fourier transform can be seen an isometry on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ which is definitely not discrete.

Comment: Should have defined question better I mean a continuous 1 dimensional variable. Like f(t) going to g(f)